# Can I indent functions and properties within interface and implementation lines?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

It bugs me that XCode does not indent class method blocks in `.h` or `.m` files. It's one of the few editors, or languages (?), that I've used that prefers to have these lines of code on the same column. So, I'm really just not used to it.

Is it possible to configure XCode so that it automatically indents functions and properties within `interface` and `implementation` lines?

Comment: While this is obviously your choice, that's how Objective-C is written. I'd recommend getting used to it, though, since others will nearly always give you code written in that style.

Comment: I absolutely hate this about xcode/obj-c, but I'm afraid @JakeKing is right. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path to sanity:

- turn on "tab always indents"
- open a source file
- select all
- hit the [tab](/questions/tagged/tab) key

Live with the result.  Seriously.   Anything else is a waste of time.

If you want, you can spend some time in the preferences mucking about.  But, no, you won't be able to have methods and/or method bodies indented because it is an exceedingly rare pattern of formatting.

Comment: you can also select multiple lines and press CMD+] or CMD+[